# Не срабатывает поиск

Tags: android, android-service, android-search-view

Мне для своего приложения, нужен поиск. И вот, нашел [видеоурок](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pVNvB5jzRpo) . Сделал все по нему, поиск появился, но я ввожу текст нажимаю кнопку поиска и ничего не происходит. Хотя должен был обновиться экран, закрыться поиск и показаться toast, но ничего не произошло. Есть идеи почему?
Кратко код:

```
 Intent myIntent = getIntent();
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(myIntent.getAction())){
            String Query = myIntent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            Toast.makeText(this, Query, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            TextOut.setText(Query);
        }
```

---

```
  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_activity_main, menu);

            SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
            SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
            searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        return true;
    }
```

UPD Код манифеста:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
        android:value=".SearchActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
        >
        </activity>>

</application>
```

Comment: в файле манифеста все прописали?.. support library используется как рекомендовано в уроке?

Comment: @ZigZag Я добавил код манифеста, проверьте пожалуйста. Я несколько раз проверял, вроде все в норме.